# Apache Ant: Run ant without showing the target names

Tags: ant, build-process, target

When I run my build file, it always shows the target name.

For example, in my build file if I have targets `A`, `B`, `C`. 
Then on when I type the command `ant A`, it shows

```
A: <...whatever>
```

How do I avoid displaying the `A`?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The command line switch is `-q`

`$ ant -q A`

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

- try -q for quiet mode
- try -emacs (not sure if this dumps the targets or not, but worth trying)
- write a custom logger

Answer (score 0):

You might also have a look at the following blog entry http://codefeed.com/blog/?p=82. The author provides some code for a custom task to set the loglevel in a build script. This way you can enable and disable log output for specific operations.